# Shake Event that can be handled regardless of the activity in Android

Tags: android, listener, android-alertdialog, shake

I am working on a project for a reusable Android component in which a shake event (user shaking the device) will prompt a dialog popup regardless of where the user is in the app.  Below is a list of problems I am facing.  I am not giving any of my code as I just need a place to start.

1. How to make it so my OnShakeListener is able to be registered in any activity, or any place the user in the apps?
2. Once my OnShakeListener has registered a shake event, how can I get the current context or activity to be used with my dialog popup?

I have looked at other posts and from what I have gathered maybe I could use the Android Application object or use Broadcast Receivers?  Hopefully there is enough information for some feedback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Build a base Activity where you register your listener. From there on, extend that Activity to any new one you need in your application. Does this fit your needs?

Comment: No I do not want a base activity.  The reason being because this will be a component put into multiple apps, and I don't want to have to go through and change the code of the apps.

Comment: Than build a separate module for this listener and add it as a dependency to your apps